# CSS Dropdown submenu width

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

so everyone has been great here with answering my questions and I really appreciate it as I'm learning :)

I am a bit confused with my current issue, as it doesn't seem to apply to everything it should.

In all of my dropdown menu's, except the last one, the menu is at least as wide as the parent, or wider. however, this isn't the case for the last menu, as it cuts off after the padding on the text ends.

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
```

site is having trouble when I try to enter my code it, so I cant past it all, heres the JSFiddle though.

http://jsfiddle.net/kocsqphs/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `min-width: 100%` to the second level `ul` should do it.

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PiranhaGeorge/kocsqphs/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the word-wrap you had given. Comment it and also if you want to give width to your div, you can also do that:

```
.main-navigation ul ul {
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
position: absolute;
z-index: 99999;
padding: 0;
width: 150%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.sub-menu{
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Hope this helps.